# How to remove dictionary items with spaces as their values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a dictionary by assigning keys to be individual characters from a string, and values to be the frequency of those characters in the string. The intention is to count the most frequent letter in the string. As I'm trying to count only letters I would like to discard spaces from counting.

I wrote the following:

```
sentence = 'This is some sentence.'

dict_characters = dict.fromkeys(sentence, 0)

for character in sentence:
    dict_characters[c] += 1

dict_letters = {k:v for k,v in dict_characters.items() if v != ' '}
```

This last line is where I'm stuck. Items that have spaces for values are not removed from the dictionary as I can tell when I print the new dictionary:

```
>>> dict_letters:  {'T': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 2, 's': 4, ' ': 3, 'o': 1, 'm': 1, 'e': 4, 'n': 2, 't
': 1, 'c': 1, '.': 1}
```

As you can see `' ': 3` is still in there. I would like it out but no matter how I try to exclude that space character in `v != ' '` part of the syntax I cannot take it out. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `v` is the value. you seem to be worried about the keys (`k`)

Comment: Building on @PaulH 's answer, it should be like this, the space is present in your key, not value
`dict_letters = {k:v for k,v in dict_characters.items() if k != '  '}`

Comment: Thank you @PaulH.

Comment: Thanks @faruk13.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong variable.

Replace

```py
dict_letters = {k:v for k,v in dict_characters.items() if v != ' '}
```

with

```py
dict_letters = {k:v for k,v in dict_characters.items() if k != ' '}
```

Note the replacement of `v` with `k`. `v` represents the value of the character; `k` is the character itself.

Comment: Got it. I somehow managed to miss the fact that space character is actually my key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the `v` while there is a key that is `' '`.

Try to change it to `k` or have both like below:

```py
dict_letters = {k:v for k,v in dict_characters.items() if v != ' ' and k != ' '}
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed to realize that.